# Woocommerce Subscriptions auto renew toggle not showing

Tags: woocommerce-subscriptions

Anyone know why the auto renewal toggle isn't showing in the account subscription area?

I have the setting enabled in woo > settings > subscriptions and we are using auth.net which allows for auto payment but the toggle is still not showing.